# SQL Parameter to Include All on ID Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters, where-clause

I'm just taking a look at the following query

```
select * from tablename
where id like '%%';
```

So that it can handle parameters to include all of the data or filtered data like bellow

```
select * from tablename
where id like '%1%';
```

Which is fine for most parameters I use but this seems wrong for an ID because it will return all data that has IDs containing 1 which I don't want

To get around this I can only append the where clause if the ID is given but that seems like a pain in the butt

Is it possible to use a different type of where clause so that a wildcard can be used in a where equals clause instead of a where like clause, example

```
select * from tablename
where id = '*';
```

So that the same query can be used to return all or filtered data? Pass parameter '*' for all or parameter '1' for ID 1 specifically

(I'm not sure if it matters for this case but I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.12 in this example)

Comment: "Postgres 9" covers **7** major versions (5 of them no longer maintained) - please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I updated the question, it's PostgreSQL 9.12 (The question is asked in a vague sense though because I have the same issue across multiple databases)

Comment: There is no version 9.12 - but using a wildcard with numbers seems rather strange to begin with.

Comment: Sorry typo, 9.6.12. The wildcard is def wrong but only to illustrate the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would often be expressed as:

```
where (id = :id or :id is null)
```

`null` is the "magic" value that represents all rows.

Comment: This is exactly what I need and seems to work in PostgreSQL, MariaDB and SQL Server. Thanks so much for such a speedy response